# Do ldc and gdc support D language contracts?

Tags: d, dmd, gdc, ldc

This code with a contract:

```
import std.stdio;

int TestContract(int a)
in
{
   assert( a > 0);
}
do
{
   return a + 1;
}

int main(string[] args)
{
   auto a = 2;
   try
   {
      writeln(a," + 1 is ",TestContract(a));
      a = -2;
      writeln(a," + 1 is ",TestContract(a));
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      writeln(e);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

compiles and runs with dmd (v2.076.0-dirty), but not ldc (0.17.1) or gdc ( 5.4.0 20160609).

ldc says:

```
contracts.d(12): Error: declaration expected, not 'do'
contracts.d(15): Error: unrecognized declaration
```

and gdc says:

```
contracts.d:12:1: error: declaration expected, not 'do'
 do
 ^
contracts.d:15:1: error: unrecognized declaration
 }
```

Edit: Compiling with "body" instead of "do", per the answer succeeds with ldc. gdc gets a new compile error:

```
/usr/include/d/core/stdc/stdarg.d:48:5: error: undefined identifier __va_list_tag
     alias __va_list = __va_list_tag;
```

Note that at the present time the dlang.org documentation for [contract programming](https://dlang.org/spec/contracts.html) does not mention that **body**, while likely deprecated, still works, and is necessary for versions of the dmd compiler earlier than [unknown version] and any versions of gdc or ldc that use a dmd front-end before version [unknown version].

Comment: ldc (0.17.5) worked for me, using `do` and not `body`.  And dmd (2.077.0) worked as well, as is no surprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `body`, not `do`. Allowing `do` instead of `body` is a very recent thing (I wasn't aware that that change had even been accepted, though it compiles with the current dmd, so I guess it was).

dmd, ldc, and gdc all share the same frontend, but they don't all have the same version. Even if you're using the most recent ldc, it's at least one, maybe two releases behind dmd, and unless you're using a development version of gdc, it's currently *way* behind (it's at 2.068 IIRC, whereas dmd 2.077.0 is in beta at the moment), though the next release they do should finally be fairly close to dmd (the frontend switch from C++ to D caused major delays for them).

Comment: Thanks. They probably should show body on the documentation page -  "23. Contract Programming". LDC can handle body, GDC gets a new error about __va_list_tag

Comment: Someone who didn't like having to use `body` probably eagerly updated the documentation when the DIP for switching to `do` and moving away from `body` being a keyword was accepted. I don't know why gdc is failing, but as I said, unless you're using a development version, it's rather old.

Comment: gdc ( 5.4.0 20160609). This version number suggests you're using a binary release from gdcproject.org? Then the druntime sources should not be located in `/usr/include/d/core/stdc/stdarg.d` and probably belong to LDC or DMD. GDC always searches for additional D files in `/usr/include/d` so you shouldn't place compiler specific include files (druntime, phobos) there.

Comment: @jpf I am using a GDC on Ubuntu 16.04 that was from package gdc-5 downloaded via Synaptic.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ldc and gdc both supports contracts. This is a recent language change - replace `do` with `body` in the contract and it compiles. You should always pay attention that you are using the same D frontend version. `ldc` shows it with `ldc2 --version`, for example.

Comment: That works with LDC, but I get a different error with gdc ( 5.4.0 20160609).  Would have tried body but "23. Contract Programming" only shows "do".  I think "body" should be added back.

Comment: The reasons for the change are given here: https://github.com/dlang/DIPs/blob/master/DIPs/DIP1003.md. I agree that the documentation should mention the `body` keyword as deprecated.